# fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, unresolved-external, cl

I'm running c++ simple opencv program, it gave me error like this

```
Starting build...
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /FeC:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\Program_C\belajar_syntax\halo.exe C:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\Program_C\belajar_syntax\halo.cpp -I C:\opencv\build\include /link /LIBPATH:C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib
halo.cpp
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(int,int,int,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QAE@HHHABV?$Scalar_@N@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::destroyAllWindows(void)" (?destroyAllWindows@cv@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
C:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\Program_C\belajar_syntax\halo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: C/C++: cl.exe build active file <

Starting build...
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /FeC:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\Program_C\belajar_syntax\halo.exe C:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\Program_C\belajar_syntax\halo.cpp -I C:\opencv\build\include /link /LIBPATH:C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib\**
halo.cpp
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(int,int,int,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QAE@HHHABV?$Scalar_@N@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::destroyAllWindows(void)" (?destroyAllWindows@cv@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
halo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
C:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\Program_C\belajar_syntax\halo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

I suspect this is because library linker problem, here is my `tasks.json`

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/nologo",
        "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "${file}",
        "-I",
        "C:\\opencv\\build\\include",
        "/link",
        "/LIBPATH:C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib\\"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$msCompile"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And this is my code I run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main() {
  // Create blue image
  Mat blueImage(10, 10, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

  // Display the image.
  imshow("grayscale image", blueImage);

  // Wait for a keystroke.
  waitKey(0);

  // Destroys all the windows created
  destroyAllWindows();
  return 0;
}
```

According `tasks.json` I'm using `cl.exe` to compile the program.

I'm new in C++ environtment after I moved from python to learn opencv because I heard C++ is fast. Like I said, I have link and include in `cl.exe` argument. But still yet error.

I also tried change `vc15` to `vc14` still give me error.

I don't install opencv from source but I downloaded from release official site with name `opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15.exe`

Here is what is inside
[image: C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib]

Comment: It looks like you're telling the linker which directory to look in, but I don't see where you're specifying the actual library file to link with.

Comment: I updated my question, I have give additional info about the directory you mean, so what library file to link with you mean?

Comment: Does it mean I should add some arguments ```/link``` in ```cl.exe```, if true, what syntax should I use?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain about this (I generally use cmake), but you might try adding the line "opencv_world460.lib" to your list of args in tasks.json

Comment: @jkb Yes I did adding the line and get still same error even there's addition error ```C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_world460d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'```

Comment: So you are using another way with ```cmake```? Can you tell me how do I do it?

Comment: It looks like you're compiling your code for 32-bit but linking to a 64-bit library. You probably want to configure your compile for 64-bit. Offhand I'm not sure how to do that for the command line. Did you open VS Code via one of the Visual Studio command-line prompts?

Comment: when I run ```cl.exe``` only yes its version ```x86```, but I changed to ```x64``` version still same error with doing this command ```C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe``` in ```command``` properties still same error

Comment: @jkb you are right this is machine architecture issue that should be x64, it seems this is because of environtment set by microsoft right after vscode opened. since ```cl.exe``` is special, I mean, In order to use ```cl.exe```, we must open vscode in ```Development Command Prompt``` instead of open vscode commonly, And make sure that ```Development Command Prompt for x64```. I found it in ```"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2022\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022"```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)